# How to get latitude and longitude

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to give input address or a place and I need to fetch latitude and longitude of that place. I am trying to use geocoder gem but it is not working. I have an address field in my users table but I don't have latitude and longitude field in my users table. I am providing an address and by that address I need to fetch latitude and longitude. What am I doing wrong?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  geocoded_by :address

 def self.find_cordinates(users)
        puts "Ssss{User.near(users.last['address'],5000).to_json}"

end


    end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `latitude` and `longitude` fields to your model

```
rails generate migration AddLatitudeAndLongitudeToUser latitude:float longitude:float
rake db:migrate
```

Than add this to `User` model

```
geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode
```

Run

```
rake geocode:all CLASS=User
```

---

If you don't want to change your model you can use utility method to get coordinates by address

```
Geocoder.coordinates("25 Main St, Cooperstown, NY")
```

Comment: What is not working? You add code above to your model and try to use `User.near()`?

Comment: May be you need to run task `rake geocode:all CLASS=User`

Comment: @Nishtha you have to provide more detail to what is not working. We are not mind readers.